# How To Loop A Sound In FL Studio?

Tags: loop

I Want To Play An Element Say Piano With Notes C E C Continuously without any gaps or intervals at same bpm how can I do that without recording completely along the whole song.

Answer (score 0):

This is really simple: create a midi or audio file with your notes and then duplicate for the wanted duration it in the arranger view.

Here are some tutorials: